# How to do Remote User -research?

Tags: user-research, user-centered-design, personas

Our product users are not local users instead they are going to be from other part of the world. How do i understand the user behavior towards product, personas, how do i draw user journey for those audience? In short, How do i do remote user research?

Answer (score 1):

To answer more fully would require a bit more of an understanding of what exactly you are trying to find out? Do you have an existing product? Are you validating a product idea or iterating an existing one?

There are a number of ways that you can approach this. A couple of techniques that may be useful include:

- If you have a current product/audience you could perform an online
  survey to help understand more about your audience.
- Arrange phone or video call interviews to explore their perception of
  the product
- Present them with some key scenarios while sharing their screen to
  understand how they might complete a given task.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.

1: If you're lucky and live in a city with a lot of foreigners, then you can invite them in and do on site research with them.

Of course, these people probably aren't totally representative of typical examples of their countrypeople (not that there is such a thing) since they're in your area. But if you can find some that have only been there a few weeks then they shouldn't be too far removed from the mental models one will find back home.

2: Remote user research itself. IMO it is inferior to onsite , talking to someone even over video chat just doesn't give the same feeling that talking to them in person does. Nonetheless it is better than nothing.

Recruit foreigners as you would local people (get in touch with any contacts in the country, if you don't have any then make some) and then set up skype sessions with them. Here it depends how you want to go. I find that strict scientifically measured usability tests are a lot harder by distance, so you may tend towards more informal discussion to try and understand them.

Generally the methodology isn't all that different to onsite UX research.

3: Reciprocal user testing. Get in touch with UX people in the target countries. Offer them exchange. They help you out by testing a little in their country and you'll help them out by testing a little in your country.

Easier said than done of course and may not be practical in a lot of organisations but if you do have the network of decent UXers whose way of working you understand and appreciate then this is the best way to go IMO.

Comment: @sheff...its an already existing product.. how do we do online survey in this scenario...can you please elaborate..give me a link/hook for the same?